# How to make for loop for expected returns of this dataset?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a vector with the expected returns of the dataset that I have but I do not know how to finish the segment off. I have a little bit of what we started with since he did not give us any more information other than this to do for loops and I am very confused. If you have any suggestions on what needs to go into the mean parentheses that would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (ii in 2:31) 
{
   expectedreturn[ii]=mean()
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you could provide a reproducible data set (either a publicly available data set like `mtcars` or `iris`) and the intended outcome.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg